# Android Studio Designs not visible yet the xml code is present

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-studio-chipmunk

I am using Android studio Chipmunk

I recently checked out to a new branch on Github and tested an app on the emulator. The app ran successfully. But when I looked at the layout resource files. They were completely blank.

[Image of blank blueprint view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvhjt.png)

[Image of blank design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajkIx.png)

Even the component tree is empty. But when I looked at the xml code, it is all there.

[Image of split view of code and design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzN2O.png)

I even tried creating a new resource xml file and tried adding a component to it. It indicates that the component has been added yet the component is not visible in the blueprint or design view. Then I tried the "Forced Refresh Layout" option.

[Forced Refresh Layout option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb12z.png)

Doing this made the component visible in the design, then I added another component and this new component was still not visible.

And this whole issue is only present in this project. If I open a different project, then the design in the resource xml files are visible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything became visible when I changed the "Theme for preview"

[image: Position of theme for preview option for reference]